# What is Python's *Args and **kwargs equivalent in PHP?

Tags: php, python, variadic-functions, language-comparisons

Lord Google isn't giving me anything besides something about declaring optional variables with a value so they can be passed into the code without giving you an error. Is there even an equivalent of *Args or **kwargs in PHP?

Cheers

Comment: PHP doesn't have anything for **kwargs AFAIK. but do your searches using the term 'associative arrays' that's what PHP folks call their dictionaries.

Comment: Briefly: `...$args` instead of `*args`. Neither variadic arguments nor argument unpacking have an equivalent for dictionaries/hash maps/associative arrays. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *Args
I think you want this `func_num_args()` please refer to this link for more
http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php

For **kwargs
This feature is not supported in php

Comment: The `...` splat has been around for over two years. It's probably more suitable, especially if the OP is more used to Python's equivalent operator.

Comment: If you're interested on how to make a function call passing kwargs from a dictionary, like `myfunction(**myargs)`, you can use [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/manual/function.call-user-func-array.php).